# C++ - Transactional memory: exact meaning of atomic_commit?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, transactions, thread-safety

#### Context:

I was reading [the Transactional memory reference.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/transactional_memory#Atomic_blocks)

Some info are *really* unclear to me.
I run the code below in godbolt and I have a sense of what should happen but I want some confirmation or explanation of what is **really expected** to happen, not what I think should happen.

In the `atomic_commit` case:

> If an exception is thrown, the transaction is committed normally.

That line raises some questions:

```
auto f() -> std::optional<int> {
    static int i = 0;

    std::optional<int> p;
    atomic_commit {  

        //some memory ops happen here
        ++i;
        throw std::runtime_error("I decide to fail here, for some reason");
        

        p = i;
        return p;  // commit transaction
    }

    return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
  for (int retries = 0 ; retries < 10 ; ++retries) {
    try {
        auto r = f();
        if (r) {
            std::cout << r.value() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        //handle the exception and maybe retry.
    }
  }
}
```

#### Question:

- What happens **exactly** to the already registered data ? Is it taken back?
- If two threads try to write at the same address, and the first one
  failed to do so, what happens to the second? is the data corrupted?
- In the case no exception is thrown, and two threads try to write in the same
  address, what happens **exactly**?

As an added info, I mostly use the latest gcc.

#### Other thoughts:

On the other hand, the `atomic_cancel` seems to have an interesting behavior:

> the values of all memory locations in the program that were modified by side effects of the operations of the atomic block are restored to the values they had at the time the start of the atomic block was executed, and the exception continues stack unwinding as usual

That would mean that all the data is copied first (may be faster than a lock).
It is the most natural behavior to me, except for the part that calling std::abort is quite rude.

But it doesn't matter, it is not always implemented anyway(gcc..).

Thanks

Comment: The cppreference page says that its description of transactional memory is incomplete, so it's no wonder that it's unclear.  Try looking at the actual standard or some better reference.

Comment: @NateEldredge I actually did this already but the resource is really scarce. Worst, since compilers don't implement it fully, info are not reliable. I will stick to what I see, ie: corrupted memory in case of a throw and be done with it..

Comment: That's a good question